# Highlighting fields in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I need to highlight a field in my application using selenium Web driver.Please send me the code for highlight any fields using selenium webdriver.Thanks in advance

Comment: Share your code, what did you try so far? Which field? What's your application's HTML etc.

Comment: <label class="placeHolder required active" for="dyij">Lainasumma</label>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will **highlight any concerned webelement with red border surrounding it**, in the page:

```
public static void highlightElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement ele) {
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",ele, "color: red; border: 2px solid red;");
    }
}
catch(Throwable t)
{
    System.err.println("Error came : " +t.getMessage());
}
```

}

For the above code to work, **you need to call the method with WebDriver instance and the concerned WebElement as the parameters**.

Say, you are calling this method from a static context, you can call like this:

```
highlightElement(driver, element);
```

Else, from a non-static context, you'll have to create an object of the class, then call this method, after that.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.. Cheers.. :)

Comment: Downvoter, please state the reason why you've downvoted it? Downvoting without any specific reason leaves less room for understanding the mistake and improving upon it. And, as I understand I have answered the question as per the OP's requirement.